# Facebook shared grey rectangle instead of proper image

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I spotted that one (just one, rest is ok) shared link on wall of group I am in isn't look properly. It's just grey rectangle, you can see it on included image. I wonder why it's displayed this way because I copied url and pasted it to facebook open graph object debugger. There are no warnings and preview generated by tool is ok (so image pass dimension requirements). I also tried to put that url on my profile and I can see image. Sorry that I don't paste urls here but I don't think I'm allowed to do this. I hope someone still want to answer my qestion. What is reason of this behaviour?

[Grey rectangle on shared link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvh0F.png)

Comment: Without the URL it is hard to tell what the issue is really. Can you provide that?

Comment: it depends on the website code at the time you posted the link, if there was no image a large enough size then that might be way. In opengraph questions usually you have to post the url or the code,  or a screenshot of the code or result with url obscured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons for this situation.
I assume you use some service provider to generate image.

1. Facebook crawler visits your site and make POST request which uses no cache content, which also makes your site fresh render for facebook request but also may cause timeout error in some cases. If image thumbnail is generated with some service provider it can be the cause.
2. Thumbnail service providers often causes mistakes by themselves. Take under consideration that what you see on facebook wall is the very first render of the image in the thumbnail provider. Check twice parameters that you send to the service and maybe there is some problem with alpha channel (if it's PNG image).

That's for my guesses. Hope it will help you.